# retrieve an element from a list of tuple with more than 2 elements (Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, tuples, nested-lists

I'm new to Haskell and need some help on this situation. I have the following list

```
-- create a type for bank account
type AcNo = String
type Name = String
type City = String
type Amnt = Int

type AcInfo = [(AcNo, Name, City, Amnt)]

-- function to get the data of bank accounts to a list of tuples
bankAccounts :: AcInfo
bankAccounts = [("oo1", "Sahan", "Colomb", 100),("002", "John", "Jafna", 200)]
```

My requirement is to get the amount corresponding to the account number, e.g., for 001 it should give 100.

The function I wrote was this

```
--Function to check the balance of a person
checkBalance :: bankAccounts -> AcNo -> Amnt
checkBalance dbase number = Amnt|(AcNo, Name, City, Amnt) <- dbase, AcNo==number}
```

The second line is where im stuck at which gives the error message

```
Syntax error in input (unexpected `|')
```

I'd like to have some help on this. Thanx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that names of Haskell types begin with capital letters, so the type of `checkBalance` should be

```
checkBalance :: AcInfo -> AcNo -> Amnt
```

In your question, you seem to aim at using a list comprehension, but you don't have the syntax quite right.

```
checkBalance dbase number = head [amnt | (acNo, name, city, amnt) <- dbase,
                                         acNo == number]
```

This definition is fine if an account is in `dbase`

```
*Main> checkBalance bankAccounts "oo1"
100
```

but blows up when it isn't.

```
*Main> checkBalance bankAccounts "001"
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

A better type for `checkBalance` is

```
checkBalance :: AcInfo -> AcNo -> Maybe Amnt
```

to represent the general case, *i.e.*, `dbase` may or may not contain `number`.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help which you have provided.Yeah. For the moment I'm only concentrating on accounts being in dbase. i will be experimenting with the type you have mentioned. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

Additional to Greg's excellent answer I want to point out that you shouldn't use tuples for bigger sets of values that constitute a logical unit. I would suggest to have an `Account` type, e.g. using record syntax, which makes things like accessing elements or making account changes more convenient:

```
data Account = Account { acNo :: AcNo
                       , name :: Name
                       , city :: City
                       , amount :: Amnt
                       } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

See http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax for details.

Then you should write functions in terms of `Account`, not in terms of `AcInfo`, and use normal list functions. Often the extractor functions provided by the record are good enough, as in your example:

```
checkBalance :: [Account] -> AcNo -> Maybe Amnt
checkBalance dbase number = fmap amount $ find (\acc -> number == acNo acc) dbase
```

Here `acNo acc` gets the account number and `amount acc` gets the amount from an account.